# Add tag <thead>, <tbody>, <tfoot> in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable, html-table, htmltable-control

I am organizing a table in my web app. The rows are created in code. I created:

```
<table id="idTab" runat="server" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <td>Campo 1</td>
  <td>Campo 2</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
  <td>Campo 1</td>
  <td>Campo 2</td>
  </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

The project is developed in VB.net. 
I need to add the lines via code inside the `<tbody>`. This does not happen unfortunately. In the compiled page tbody tag, tfoot, thead disappear and are left only the tr. How can I leave them? They heater it for the table template.

Comment: What does your VB code in code behind look like?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use GridView?